# Don't display slide number in shiny/rmarkdown presentation?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

Is it possible to remove the slide numbers from the bottom right corner in a shiny/markdown presentation?  I feel like it's a simple command that I just haven't come across yet.

Thanks!

Comment: I remember someone asked the same question either on the rmarkdown website or on Github. I cannot find it now. Was that you?

Comment: Hey Yihui.  That wasn't me.  I'll take a look around today and see if it was answered.  Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [customize the CSS](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/ioslides_presentation_format.html) and remove the page numbers:

```
slides > slide:not(.nobackground):after {
  content: ""
}
```

Comment: @maloneypatr Okay I finally found it on Github: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/244